# read all columns from a text file in unix and frame sql query

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I have a column.txt file in unix folder having columns as below:

col1

col2

col3

i want to create a query like below by reading column.txt file using shell script:

SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) as col1_null_count,

SUM(CASE WHEN col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as col2_null_count,

SUM(CASE WHEN z is null then 1 else 0 end) as col3_null_count

FROM table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop and iterate through each line of your column's file. Example below:

```
$ cat column.txt
col1
col2
col3
col4


echo "SELECT"
for i in `cat column.txt`
    do 
        echo "SUM(CASE WHEN $i is null then 1 else 0 end) as ${i}_null_count,"
    done
echo "FROM table;"
```

Comment: Thanks it is working,  the only problem is just before "FROM" "," is coming and it is preventing me to run sql query. any method to remove last comma before FROM